# SQL - Get data from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've read other threads about getting queries from 2 tables, but I still don't now how to implement my issue.

There is a Feed page where user gets queries from **Table A** sorted by date. And there is another **Table B** that contains some queries. I need to get queries from both tables, mix them, and sort by date.

**Table A**

```
----id----  ----date---- ----post----
1           20170514     post 1
2           20170512     post 3
3           20170510     post 5
```

**Table B**

```
----id----  ----date---- ----post---- ----thread----
1           20170513     post 2       1
2           20170511     post 4       2
```

`SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE post!="" AND date!=""` and `SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE post!="" AND date!=""`

Output (in plaint text to screen) should be:

1. table: Table A, post: post 1, date: 20170514
2. table: Table B, post: post 2, date: 20170513
3. table: Table A, post: post 3, date: 20170512
4. table: Table B, post: post 4, date: 20170511
5. table: Table A, post: post 5, date: 20170510

Comment: See UNION, but your ids make no sense.

Comment: @Strawberry but if tables have different number of columns?

Comment: It makes no difference because you always name all the columns you want in a query

Comment: How many columns are in the tables doesn't matter. It's about which you select. One can do for instance: `select col1, 'xx' as col2, col3 from t1 union all select cola, colb, null from t2`. You see, although the tables are different, you can still use `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UNION like this

```
SELECT id, date, post FROM TABLEA
WHERE date IS NOT NULL AND
post IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT id, date, post FROM TABLEB
WHERE date IS NOT NULL AND
post IS NOT NULL
```

you may need to use alias for the tables.

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like to see a result-set containing both tables' rows, you should use `JOIN` but in this case, you should be able to connect those two tables. For example if you have a `product` table, and a `product_details`, then you should have a field on the second table like `product_id` which is pointing to an existing product's id. you can find out more here:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Otherwise you could try `UNION` which is used to combine two ore more result-ser of multiple `SELECT` statements:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp